# Can we use comparison test for testing the convergence of following series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(\pi \sqrt{n^2+k^2}) , k\in \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am not sure if I've understood this well, problem is following:
Test the convergence of following series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(\pi \sqrt{n^2+k^2})  , k\in \mathbb{Z}$$
My question is how can we do a comparison test here because there is no large N such that elements of series bigger than N are constant signs? My teacher has written $$\pi(n^2 + k^2) ^ {\frac{1}{2}} = n \pi + \frac{k^2 \pi }{2n} + o(\frac{1}{n})$$ From that we can easy get $$\sin(\pi \sqrt{n^2+k^2}) = (-1)^n \frac{k^2 \pi }{2n} + o(\frac{1}{n})$$ I understand all of that and now we say that initial series converge because $(-1)^n \frac{k^2 \pi }{2n} + o(\frac{1}{n})$ converges using Leibnitz test. Here we use comparison test to say that initial series act like $(-1)^n \frac{k^2 \pi }{2n} + o(\frac{1}{n})$ but can we really say that? I think not all neccessary conditions for comparison test are fulfilled.

Comment: The term $o(1/n)$ is also $O(1/n^3)$ in this case.  And the series $\sum_{n\ge 1}O(1/n^3)$ is absolutely convergent.

Comment: Indeed the terms being $o(1/n)$ is insufficient to guarantee convergence - a famous example is $\sum_n 1/(n \log n)$.